# Как записать данные в определенный блок в другом файле?

Tags: php

Для записи данных в другой файл использую следующий код:

```
 $f = fopen('pl1.html', 'a');
  fwrite($f, $content . PHP_EOL);
  fclose($f);
```

но как записать данные в определенный div в другом файле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данные можно записать в 3 файла и тогда с помощью функции

```
$f=fopen('3.html','r'); 
fpassthru($f); 
fclose($f);
```

вывести в нужном месте в 2 файле